# How to get pathname of image from FileUpload in grid view

Tags: asp.net

Hello i have my FileUpload in gridview.I upload image for every row and then click button called UPLOAD. So that it should get image path from every row and upload. Onclick listener  for UPLOAD is `UploadBtn_onClick`.
Code for `UploadBtn_onClick` is

```
protected void UploadBtn_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in StudentGrid.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        UpdateEmailProperties objUpdateEmailId = new UpdateEmailProperties();

                        GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((FileUpload)sender).NamingContainer;
                        FileUpload filename = (FileUpload)grdrow.Cells[5].FindControl("fileuploadimages");


                        objUpdateEmailId.StudId =  int.Parse(row.Cells[6].Text);
                        objUpdateEmailId.Email = row.Cells[3].Text;
                        objUpdateEmailId.profilepath = "profilepics/" + filename;

                        int intStatus;
                        intStatus = Stud.UpdateStudentEmailId(objUpdateEmailId);
                        if (intStatus != 0)
                        {
                            lblWarning.Text = "Updated successfully";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblWarning.Text = "Failed to Update";
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //LogFile.CreateLog("User", "AddPlacement", ex.Message);
                        lblWarning.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message.ToString();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But i am getting error as

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload'
```

[image: I need to fetch name of file returned from loadfile].

**`I need to fetch name of file returned from loadfile`**

Comment: Button filename = (Button)grdrow.Cells[5].FindControl("fileuploadimages"). Are you sure you are referencing correct control?

Comment: No.I want to know how to write this control

Comment: fileuploadimages is id of FileUpload .I,e <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image Url">
                      <HeaderStyle Width="150px" CssClass="Header-Style"/>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileuploadimages" runat="server" />
                             </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>